# Review site using Wordpress

Tags: theme-development, mobile

I have my domian viewport.mobi, I want to create mobile review site like http://www.mobileawesomeness.com/ , I think its created in wordpress.

Can anyone suggest a free or paid theme available for wordpress. so I can post screenshot of the mobile site and the review, also Open for Comments.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The most comprehensive review plugin is GD star rating. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/

A theme is very subjective, you can integrate this plugin with any theme, I would suggest browsing the theme repository for one you like, http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/

To be specific in terms of layout your looking for a "showcase" theme.